# SSRS spatial Bubble map - Hide bubbles for 0 values

Tags: sql, reporting-services, geospatial, ssrs-2012, reporting-services-map

In SSRS, when you add a map and select *"Bubble map"* in the wizard, the map will display bubbles for *0* values too.
I’m trying to visualize data as per follows:

[image: map layer settings]

It doesn’t matter if you count a field or sum. SSRS seems to show bubbles everywhere when there is a match on the spatial and the analytical table. Country_code in my case.

[image: results]

**Can somebody please help me to hide the bubbles when the analytical data = 0 ?**

Comment: Can't you just filter your dataset and remove zeros?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out how to do this with a little trick.

**Right-click the map**>**Center Point properties**>**General**>Click the **function button** next to the **Marker type** field and type the following expression:

```
=iif(Fields!Your_analytical_field.Value=0,"None","Circle")
```

Or if you want to do this only for null values:

```
=iif(Fields!Your_analytical_field.Value is nothing,"None","Circle")
```

That's it !

Don't know if this is the best way to accomplish what you need, but it's working anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to filter your spatial dataset by joining with the analytical one. If using cube data, use openquery to join like that :

```
SELECT a.*
FROM 
(SELECT your_geo_data, some_matching_id FROM SpatialData) a
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT "[some hierarchy].[some_other_matching_id]" some_other_matching_id FROM OPENQUERY(YOUR_LINKED_SERVER, 'SELECT NON EMPTY { ... } on 0 FROM ... ' ) ) b
on a.some_matching_id = b.some_other_matching_id
```

The problem here might be performance as you would run the analytical dataset query twice, one for the analytical dataset itself and one for the join.